# How to create a table and choose any column in database?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

Write a function named "create_table" that doesn't take any parameters and doesn't return a value. This function will create a table named "spokesman" with any columns you choose in a database with the file name "region.db". If the table already exists your program should not crash (ie. your function will be called twice and should work properly on both calls).

```
import sqlite3
def create_table():
    conn=sqlite3.connect('region.db')
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE spokesman (first text)")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

What am I doing wrong, getting table spokesman already exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means you have already executed the program before and therefore the table has already been created. You can not create a new table with the same name as an existing table. So if you have executed the program twice, you will get that error.

Therefore, change the SQL command to `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS spokesman (first text)`.

So the whole program shall be as follows:

```
import sqlite3

def create_table():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('region.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS spokesman (first text)")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```